# Python. Django iterating a ridiculous amount more times over queryset. Very extrange

Tags: django, django-queryset

Can someone explain me this:

```
>>> from inicio.models import EventoSubasta
>>> procesos_concluidos = EventoSubasta.objects.filter(concluido=True, eliminado=False).order_by("-fechasubasta__fecha")
>>> procesos_concluidos.count()
7
>>> for proceso in procesos_concluidos:
...   print "proceso.codigo_proceso: %s - proceso.id: %s " % (proceso.codigo_proceso, proceso.id)
... 
proceso.codigo_proceso: SP010-2016 - proceso.id: 15 
proceso.codigo_proceso: SP010-2016 - proceso.id: 15 
proceso.codigo_proceso: SP010-2016 - proceso.id: 15 
proceso.codigo_proceso: SP010-2016 - proceso.id: 15 
proceso.codigo_proceso: SP010-2016 - proceso.id: 15 
proceso.codigo_proceso: SP010-2016 - proceso.id: 15 
proceso.codigo_proceso: SP010-2016 - proceso.id: 15 
proceso.codigo_proceso: SP006-2016 - proceso.id: 13 
proceso.codigo_proceso: SP005-2016 - proceso.id: 8 
proceso.codigo_proceso: SP003-2016 - proceso.id: 5 
proceso.codigo_proceso: SP004-2016 - proceso.id: 9 
proceso.codigo_proceso: SP002-2016 - proceso.id: 4 
proceso.codigo_proceso: SP001-2016 - proceso.id: 3 
>>>
```

Isn't it supposed to iterate once over each object in the queryset? why is it repeating the object with id 15 seven times. I don't understand. The project is in production. Please help.

**EDIT**

If I remove `order_by`, it works:

```
>>> procesos_concluidos = EventoSubasta.objects.filter(concluido=True, eliminado=False)
>>> for p in procesos_concluidos:
...   print p.id
... 
4
3
5
15
9
8
13
```

**Adding disctinct() doesn't work:**

```
>>> procesos_concluidos = EventoSubasta.objects.filter(concluido=True, eliminado=False).order_by("-fechasubasta__fecha").distinct()
>>> for p in procesos_concluidos:
...   print p.id
... 
15
15
15
15
15
15
15
13
8
5
9
4
3
>>> procesos_concluidos = EventoSubasta.objects.filter(concluido=True, eliminado=False).distinct().order_by("-fechasubasta__fecha")
>>> for p in procesos_concluidos:
...   print p.id
... 
15
15
15
15
15
15
15
13
8
5
9
4
3
```

Comment: Can you please include the model definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks a lot to Sayse for pointing me to the docs so I can read the cause of the problem. Tried adding `distinct()` but it didn't work (I added that to the question) . This is what solved it:

```
lista_b = sorted(lista, key=lambda x : x.fechasubasta_set.last().fecha, reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs for Interaction with default ordering or order_by()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/aggregation/#interaction-with-default-ordering-or-order-by)

> Fields that are mentioned in the order_by() part of a queryset (or which are used in the default ordering on a model) are used when selecting the output data, even if they are not otherwise specified in the values() call. **These extra fields are used to group “like” results together and they can make otherwise identical result rows appear to be separate**

Comment: Add `.distinct()` to the query if you need the cross-table `order_by`, as discussed in the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct